# VueJS - vue.config.js proxy configuration for build

Tags: node.js, vue.js, proxy, cross-domain

I'm currently using `devServer{proxy:{...}}` in vue.config.js to configure proxy for api calls for avoiding CORS problems in my application. It works fine when I run `npm run serve` in localhost.

Now I need to deploy my application to a host, so I run `npm run build`, change the url's of my Ajax calls and it's not running... So what I indeed need is to configure my proxy for deployment (build), not for devServer.

What is the correct way to do that?

I've already tried:
`server{proxy:{...}}` and `build{proxy:{...}}`, but none of them are allowed when running `npm run build`.

Thank you!

Comment: Have found solution for this? I am too facing same issue.. Can you please update if yes

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106295/npm-run-build-does-not-use-proxy

Comment: Have you tried maybe getting a chrome extenstion for CORS and removing the config from the vue.config?

Comment: What is the outcome of this question ? Remove the proxy from config and use the complete url with  VUE_APP_API_URL from .env ?

Answer (score 11):

You can try another approach which is adding API URL's to .env files

If you are using Vue CLI you can create **.env.development** and **.env.production** files and put API URL's for development and production like:

**.env.development**

```js
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8080/api
```

**.env.production**

```js
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://myapp.com/api
```

In your project files you can access the variables by putting **VUE_APP_** keyword like;

**Your file to make api requests**

```js
const url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
const res = axios.get(url, config).then (...)
                                  .catch(...)
```

You can look for more from [Vue's official docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html)

To handle the CORS issue, I can give you some tips.

1. Divide your app as packages named server and client
2. Move everything related to vuejs to client folder
3. Move server.js to server folder
4. Implement cardconnect inside server.js
5. Create an nodejs api via expressjs and move cardconnect logic to controllers(endpoints)
6. Consume nodejs api that makes cardconnect implementation via vue.js(this will resolve the cors issue since you dont make requests from vuejs, but triggering the cardconnect implementation via node.js)
7. Serve Vue app with your Node.js server

Comment: As you said, i have created .env.development -> API_URL=http://localhost:8080/ and  .env.production -> API_URL=https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/. And called  const url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL in axios post method     const URL = url+'/cardsecure/api/v1/ccn/tokenize'; But its showing error POST http://localhost:8080/undefined/cardsecure/api/v1/ccn/tokenize 404 (Not Found). And one thing i have commented all lines inside vue.config.js file

Comment: @PvDev sorry my mistake, you need to define the API URL also with VUE_APP keyword, so instead of **API_URL**, define them as **VUE_APP_API_URL** in your env files, I edited my answer as well

Comment: whether i will face corss origin policy issue for production. Because i have website in  http:dev-xxx-firebaseapp.com and my api from cardconnect. https://fts.cardconnect:6443/ i have already faced this issue that's why asking

Comment: xhr.js?b50d:178 POST http://localhost:8080/cardsecure/api/v1/ccn/tokenize 404 (Not Found) whether i need add something in vue.config.js. cause i have commented all lines in vue.config.js

Comment: I understand, so there are two ways I know, one of them is define a CORS filter in your api and let your website domain to reach server with CORS configuration, second way is serving your website  from api application so they will be in the same domain

Comment: my domain https://dev-cloudthrifty-com.firebaseapp.com and my payment gateway api url https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/

Comment: Can you try reaching localhost:8080/cardsecure/api/v1/ccn/tokenize via postman to make sure api endpoint is present and reachable?

Comment: In localhost it works fine by setup vue.config.js like   devServer: {
         
      proxy: 'https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/'
    } but build version it shows cors policy blocked issue. Past three days i'm struck on this. can you help me out of this..

Comment: Okey so you can delete vue.config.js proxy configuration and start using env files, if you build your application vue will get the env. variables from .env.production

Comment: xhr.js?b50d:178 POST localhost:8080/cardsecure/api/v1/ccn/tokenize 404 (Not Found) still facing this issue

Comment: Interesting, do you get this error in development or in production?

Comment: developement. i didnt tested in production let me test. do you have skype id so that i can share my some code to you. can you help me

Comment: sry for asking skype id.. now i'm facing cors issue in production xhr.js:178 OPTIONS https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/cardconnect/rest/auth 401 (Unauthorized)
/list-server:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/cardconnect/rest/auth' from origin 'https://dev-cloudthrifty-com.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I was going to share my email no problem, so your problem is you need to add CORS filter in your API application and allow your website domain and then authenticate

Comment: voiltan_93@hotmail.com

Comment: @onuriltan : I have remove the proxy and accessing api with complete url on production now facing cors issue ?

Answer (score 10):

**Vue CLI, by default, will not ship a webserver like the proxy, it will deploy bundled Javascript in a `dist/` directory.**

1. The proxy isn't meant to be deployed to production and that's why you're not finding information about deploying with it.
2. If you're serving a static `/dist` directory, find the instructions [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html) for your provider (S3, Netlify, Firebase) and follow them.

#### Longer answer:

You're running into an issue because the proxy is not supposed to be used for production. The proxy Vue CLI is shipping with is [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/). It is used by Vue CLI to enable you to serve your Javascript files locally during development.

There are security vulnerabilities if you use webpack-dev-server (aka the proxy) in prod. Don't do it.

Instead, you need to find the hosting provider you're using and follow the instructions here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html to deploy your application. If your application is personal or can be public, I suggest using [Netlify](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#netlify).

**For example...** In my production setup, we deploy to an AWS S3 bucket and serve content with either AWS Cloudfront CDN or the Fastly CDN. Our API urls are always the production server ones, and we use [this setting in the proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) to pass through to our local server

Comment: thanks for answering. here i'm yarn build. its works fine in localhost:8080 by creating vue.config.js deveserver proxy url. How to do build version.  I'm totally new to vuejs. I have already asked this question and share some part of code there. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165377/xmlhttprequest-https-fts-cardconnect-com6443-cardconnect-rest-auth-from-ori?noredirect=1#comment98963587_56165377 .. Can you pls help me out of this..